# Need to hide a field for the node author

Tags: nodes, theming

For a particular content type education i need a field to be hidden for the node author. It works in the template file but not with preprocess. This is my code

```
 function aapka_preprocess_node(&$variables){
     $node = $variables['node'];
     if ($node->type == 'education'){
     if ($node->uid == $user->uid && $user->uid != 1) {
 unset($variables['content']['field_college']);}
  }
```

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Can you try to do this functionality in a node template file ?

note--education.tpl.php , just copy paste it from the normal node.tpl.php and adjust it accordingly

Comment: It works in a template file am just looking for it to work in preprocess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing $user without bringing it into scope.

e.g using your current approach you could do this:

```
function aapka_preprocess_node(&$variables){
  // Bring global user object into scope
  global $user;
  // Assign by reference
  $node =& $variables['node'];
  if ($node->type == 'education'){
    if ($node->uid == $user->uid && $user->uid != 1) {
      unset($variables['content']['field_college']);
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that won't work if the node is cached and the cache doesn't vary between the author and other regular registered users.

Comment: Thanks it works. Am only using default drupal cache for anonymous users. Also is it better to do this in the node template file than preprocess??